# Threading function that takes variables and returns a datatable in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, function

I've been looking at threading to make my webapplications more responsive. I've found out how to thread a sub that takes no variables and doesn't return anything, but I can't find out how to achieve this for a function that takes variables and returns something.

here is an example

```
      Public Function getParkingsByCrossSerial(ByVal crossSerial As String) As dsGuest.tblParkingGuestDataTable

    Try

        Return _adapterParking.selectParkingByCrossSerial(crossSerial)

    Catch ex As Exception

        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)

    End Try

End Function
```

How do I translate this to a thread?

Thanks!

Comment: Try this... there are some examples<br>
http://blog.dotnetclr.com/archive/2007/04/15/Starting-a-new-thread-with-parameters.aspx

Comment: This helped in passing a parameter...Still need to fix the returnpart. I'll think I'll give this a try. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ywkkz4s1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To take params, you are going to have to work with objects that you pass as you start your thread. That should be too hard, but there are a few ways of doing so.

But in order to get a response, you are looking for callbacks, if ever you want to work in async(which is what you want I assume ?)

You could also come back with events, and store the return in some class variable.